# Hibernate criteria distinct by joined table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, distinct

I have a table A that, among other have a field of a foreign key of Table B.
I want to fetch (Criteria API preferred, HQL OK too) X entries of **A** that have unique B references,

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM A AS a
WHERE a.b IN (SELECT ax.b 
              FROM A AS ax 
              GROUP BY b HAVING COUNT(b) = 1)
```